# Resolve dollar in dollar variable in unix

Tags: shell-script, shell

For example :-

```
Path1=/home/xyz/
echo $Path1
Path2=${Path1}abc.dat
```

I want output as Path2

```
echo $Path2
/home/xyz/abc.dat
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you need? Do you want `echo $Path2` to return `/home/xyz/abc.dat` or something else?

Comment: The code _seems_ to do what you are asking for (apart from additionally outputting `$Path1`).

Comment: The question itself is the answer. I think the OP was trying to ask something else. Please consider editing the question as it does not make any sense.

Comment: my bad.. i have already answer my question..

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Method 1

```
Path1=/home/xyz/
echo $Path1"abc.dat"
```

Method 2

```
Path1=/home/xyz/
Path2=`echo $Path1|awk '{print $0"abc.dat"}'`
echo $Path2
```

Comment: Using a command substitution with deprecated backticks plus `awk` is really not necessary here. And variables with an uppercase first letter are bad style, no need to copy it from the question. And it doesn't hurt to quote your variables…